# UI-GRID header - Change Color And Text

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want to change the color and text of the angular ui-grid header.

I want the background of the header to be black and the text to be white.

I don't want gradient or shading. I just want it black.

What CSS do I need to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Just add a headerCellClass for each column with your css.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name', headerCellClass: 'white' },
      { field: 'company',headerCellClass:'white'}
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, function( grid, sort ) {
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
      })
    }
  };
```

here's a sample

http://plnkr.co/edit/DKi9nSMbI3PG1u8lcHDE?p=preview

Comment: If I want to use color code like: `#3A01DF` how does that work? Simply replacing `white` with `#3A01DF` doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is already answered. But this css rule does the same job without the need of creating columDefs:

```
.ui-grid-top-panel {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rERmzQCW2w3f3Z5G89xw?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to change the background color of all `ui-grid header` use the following in your CSS file.

```
.ui-grid-header-canvas{
    background-color: black;
}
.ui-grid-top-panel{
    color: white;
}
```

Otherwise, if you need to change the background color of specific `ui-grid headers`, then use `headerCellClass` attribute.