# Color codes doesn't work on ui-grid headerCellClass

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to set the color of the header using `headerCellClass` as in this example:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name', headerCellClass: 'white' },
  { field: 'company',headerCellClass:'white'}
],
```

[UI-GRID header - Change Color And Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583429/ui-grid-header-change-color-and-text)

Rather having set color codes like 'white', 'red etc. I'm trying to use color codes: `headerCellClass: '#3A01DF'` but its not working. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the color - white - set in your css? Like:

```
.white { color: white;background-color:black !important;  }
```

Comment: I want to use color codes like `#3A01DF` not `white`

Comment: Yes, so when you set the color in your css, just do: 

`.color { color: #3A01DF; !important; }`

So when you set the color of `headerCellClass` it'll take the color code from your css:

`columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name', headerCellClass: 'color' },
  { field: 'company',headerCellClass:'color'}
],`

Comment: I want to set my color dynamic though so can't really add it in the css file: `'headerCellClass: '{ color:' + option.color + '!important; }'`

Answer (score 1):

You can set different classes in css (red, default-class, black etc.):

```
.red {
    background-color: red !important;
    color: #F3F3F3 !important;
}

.default-class {
    background-color: #004A75 !important;
    color: #FFFF00 !important;
}

.black {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

and in `headerCellClass` a function, which returns a proper class depending on condition (or just one class):

```
headerCellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    if (condition === 1) 
        return 'red';
    if (condition === 2)
        return 'black';

    return 'default-class';
},
```

Sample from ui-grid: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/115_headerCellClass